# App crashes on iOS when using Link SDK Assemblies Only

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have created a Dynamic Template in a List View. When data fills in List View, the app crashes. This only happens when we use Link SDK Assemblies Only.

Crash report below:

```
{"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 9.3.5 (13G36)","build_version":"1.0","timestamp":"2017-02-15 11:53:42.42 +0530","app_name":"projectiOS","bundleID":"com.abc.Project","name":"projectiOS","is_first_party":false,"app_version":"1","share_with_app_devs":true,"slice_uuid":"6bc7264a-bf7d-34b4-9600-f8f7219318a7","adam_id":0}
Incident Identifier: 9C79A0BA-649B-4178-A0F6-E95921306D31
CrashReporter Key:  42623b495537be281f0b0ea904ae9508c91fa1f8
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:            projectiOS [11783]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/41311D3F-C17A-4E43-952F-EBB8058D8FA2/projectiOS.app/projectiOS 
Identifier:          com.abc.Project
Version:            1.0 (1)
Code Type:          ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:          2017-02-15 11:53:40.40 +0530
Launch Time:        2017-02-15 11:52:22.22 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xffffffff
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_a0b  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x2247ec5c 0x2246a000 + 85084
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib      0x22528732 0x22524000 + 18226
2  libsystem_c.dylib            0x224130ac 0x223c8000 + 307372
3  InstaClassesiOS              0x00174d14 0xe4000 + 593172
4  InstaClassesiOS              0x0017c60c 0xe4000 + 624140
5  libsystem_platform.dylib      0x22522076 0x2251d000 + 20598
6  QuartzCore                    0x24df8b10 0x24df5000 + 15120
7  QuartzCore                    0x24df8b10 0x24df5000 + 15120
8  QuartzCore                    0x24df8590 0x24df5000 + 13712
9  QuartzCore                    0x24dfb5f6 0x24df5000 + 26102
10  QuartzCore                    0x24dfb42e 0x24df5000 + 25646

0x3311f000 - 0x3313efff CoreServicesInternal armv7  <db484f452bf437a993bf39423f6efd67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x333a1000 - 0x333acfff libGSFontCache.dylib armv7  <7361c8f4b3cb303b81c503ece2d4f220> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
0x346d5000 - 0x354d0fff KBLayouts_iPhone.dylib armv7  <3cf3fb517b533b73baa79471c768913c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/KBLayouts_iPhone.dylib

Error Formulating Crash Report:
Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
```

Comment: Symbolicate your crash so you can see what is being called in the thread backtrace

Comment: how we can Symbolicate ?? Any example?? @SushilHangover

Comment: @ChetanRawat Check out this tutorial: http://jmillerdev.net/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios/

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/questions/symbolicate-ios-crash/

Comment: i can't understand symbolicate meaning can you help me to understand this file @SushiHangover

Comment: Please bind this symbolicated error here http://pastebin.com/xgRAz9E6